# Unexplained frame rate decay

Tags: technical-issues, borderlands-2, performance, windows

When I open the game (or any game on my PC) it will go to a high FPS (like 60+) but then i can watch the frame rate tick down slowly until it hovers around 10-13 FPS. It does this to EVERY game. but it isn't that my computer can't handle it (Borderlands 2 suggests all settings on high). It also makes no difference what the video settings are for Borderlands 2.

One more thing, when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> out and then back in the frame rate goes up to 25-30 and then starts to fall back to crap.

#### System

- Total amount of system memory 12.0 GB RAM
- System type 64-bit operating system
- Number of processor cores 4

#### Storage

- Total size of hard disk(s) 3391 GB
- Disk partition (C:) 81 GB Free (581 GB Total)
- Disk partition (D:) 8 GB Free (15 GB Total)
- Media drive (E:) CD/DVD
- Disk partition (Y:) 131 GB Free (2794 GB Total)

#### Graphics

- Display adapter type AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series

  - Total available graphics memory 6907 MB
  - Dedicated graphics memory 1024 MB
  - Dedicated system memory 0 MB
  - Shared system memory 5883 MB
- Display adapter driver version 8.930.0.0
- Primary monitor resolution 1920x1200
- DirectX version DirectX 10

Comment: Have you tried the basic diagnostic steps ? IE: reformatting your OS, interchanging your video card with a different one, stress testing on your MOBO, etc ?  This might be a question for the SuperUser StackExchange...

Comment: Do you have any sort of in-game overlay?

Comment: I use fraps to monitor FPS and before you ask, no it's not recording.
@Foxtrot Would reformatting my OS help? and what does that entail? (I'm not completely new to computers but definitely not advanced)
I don't have another vid-card to swap.

Answer (score 7):

Your video card, and probably the rest of you computer, is likely overheating.  Have you tried cleaning it out (dust cleaners/blowers)?

When you Alt+Tab out, your video card essentially gets a quick relief from processing your games, and cools down a little bit.

Comment: overheating is likely. Could be either the cpu or graphics card. Cleaning definetely recommended. Do you have any recommendations for temperature monitoring software?

Comment: I will check that and get back to you

Comment: ok... it very well could be heat related.
I opened up the case and while dust was present, it wasn't enough to effect anything.
However, i noticed that the GPU fan isn't spinning! i tested it out in borderlands and even under load it got hot but the fan didn't engage.
If you have a ready solution to that let me know, but I am going to try to look into if it's something i can fix or if it's a defective fan or whatnot.

Comment: Ok, i looked at the fan and I think I found the culprit:
a dust bunny the size of a dime was caught between the centercap of the fan and the shaft. I think this'll do the trick (facepalm)

Comment: Lol glad to help. This type of behavior is common on less powerful graphic cards as well; they're under more of a load processing the same games.

Comment: @Colin D:  Speedfan is one of the most common, but it does depend on some of your hardware not having blocked temperature reading functions.  If you built your computer yourself, you're likely going to be good.

Comment: I might be looking into an aftermarket fan soon, if not a new vid-card altogether
=)

Comment: What GPU do you have right now? Aftermarket fan for your... GPU?

Comment: yes, at least, i think that's possible... right?

Comment: Agree, I was gaming for a long time without pausing, and as a result, my graphics card burned out. I literally saw it die, little by little.